# Scipy Showing Steps When Solving?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am testing out Scipy and its useful features when it comes to solving equations. I discovered I can use Scipy to solve a Gauss-Jordan Elimination problem like this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la

A = np.array([
    [1,2,3],
    [1,3,8],
    [1,2,2]
])
b = np.array([1,1,2]).reshape((-1,1))

print('{}'.format(la.solve(A, b)))
```

However, I was hoping to show the steps on how to do it. Like what rows did it subtract to get there and show the final answer? Similar to something like this? 
[image: Example]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You can use `lu_factor`, which will give you L and U factors and the pivot array.